# Multiple file reading from a directory using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to read multiple files using pandas. I made a list of filenames. I was trying to iterate the list. And I was trying to pass each elements as a parameter of pd.read_csv() syntax. But got some error. Here is the code-

```
import pandas as pd

for i in lst1:
    temp=pd.read_csv(i)
    print(temp)
```

Here is the list-

```
['test0.txt', 'test4.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt']
```

Here is the error-

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [This is test print]
Index: []

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-0112d2ad4f18> in <module>
      2 
      3 for i in lst1:
----> 4     temp=pd.read_csv(i)
      5     print(temp)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    683         )
    684 
--> 685         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    686 
    687     parser_f.__name__ = name

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    455 
    456     # Create the parser.
--> 457     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    458 
    459     if chunksize or iterator:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1133     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1134         if engine == "c":
-> 1135             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1136         else:
   1137             if engine == "python":

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1915         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1916 
-> 1917         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1918         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1919 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'test4.txt' does not exist: b'test4.txt'
```

Comment: Please add more information, what is `lst1`?

Comment: Check your files. One of them might be empty.

Comment: probably you do not have `test4.txt` in the same folder where you are executing the script.

Comment: Probably, the file does not exist in the directory / folder where you are executing.